# Is it possible to determine when a target last went up/down?

Tags: prometheus

Prometheus provides the `up()` function which tells you if a target is up or down. You can count how many times this has changed in a given time-period using `changes()` and you can even use `avg_over_time()` to see what % of the time it's up.

But I would like to find the time *when* the value changed, specifically to find how long a target has been up (or down). Is this possible? Clearly I can add my own metrics but I would rather not have to add new metrics to every instrumented target if possible.

Comment: Have you sorted out how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following example:

```
time() - max_over_time(timestamp(changes(up[1m]) > 0)[24h:1m])
```

This query is based on the max timestamp where there have been any changes during the last N minutes (`1m` in my example). Subtracted from current time will give you the number of seconds from the latest update.
Make sure you use the interval that is at least as long as your scrape interval and ideally quite a bit longer, in order to cover any missed scrapes etc.
Just play around with various metrics and intervals and pick the ones which work best for you.

For efficiency reasons, you could also consider adding a recording rule, something like:

```
groups:

- name: last-update
  rules:

  - record: last-update
    expr: |
      timestamp(changes(up[1m]) > 0)
        or
      last-update
```